# C# - Type parameter hides class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm having trouble with the following class

```
public class ComplaintExternalRepairEvaluatedOutgoingMessageDtoFactory: IOutgoingMessageDtoFactory
{
    public async Task<OutgoingMessageDto<T>> Create<T>(ValidatedIncomingMessageDto incomingMessage) where T: IMergeInputDto
    {
        ...
        return new OutgoingMessageDto<T>(
            ...
            await GetMergeInput<T>(param1, param2, param3)
        );
    }

    private async Task<MergeInputDto> GetMergeInput<MergeInputDto>(long param1, long param2, long param3)
    {
        return new MergeInputDto(...);
    }
```

The `IOutgoingMessageDtoFactory` interface looks like this

```
public interface IOutgoingMessageDtoFactory
{
    Task<OutgoingMessageDto<T>> Create<T>(ValidatedIncomingMessageDto incomingMessage) where T: IMergeInputDto;
}
```

The error I'm getting is in the `ComplaintExternalRepairEvaluatedOutgoingMessageDtoFactory` class on the private method at `GetMergeInput<MergeInputDto>`. The error is `Type parameter 'MergeInputDto' hides class 'MergeInputDto'`

I've tried renaming `MergeInputDto` to things like `TMergeInputDto` but then I get an error on the `await GetMergeInput<T>` line saying `Argument type 'MergeInputDto' is not assignable to parameter type 'T'`

I have no idea how to solve this. Anyone with ideas?

Comment: What does `MergeInputDto` do? And why is `GetMergeInput` generic?

Comment: `MergeInputDto` is a basic class with some properties. I have a different class that contains a property `T MergeInput`. It's generic because `MergeInput` will have multiple implementations that all have different properties. That's why the `MergeInput` class implements the `IMergeInput` interface.
First I had `IMergeInput MergeInput` as a typed property in the other class, but that resulted in problems with serializing. So that's why I went with generics.

Comment: Why have you called a type parameter `MergeInputDto`? Do you *actually* want `GetMergeInput` to be a generic method? (Your `Create` method can be generic without `GetMergeInput` being generic.) I suspect you actually just want `private async Task<MergeInputDto> GetMergeInput(long param1, long param2, long param3)`. If you *really* want that method to be generic, I strongly recommend using a conventional name for the type parameter, e.g. `TMerge`, and potentially adding a constraint on it. Fundamentally we don't have enough information about what you're trying to do. A [mcve] would help.

Comment: When you call `new MergeInputDto(...)` are you expecting to create an instance of the actual `MergeInputDto` class, or an instance of the type argument? Because you can't call any constructor other than a parameterless one (with a suitable constraint) if you're trying to create an instance of the type argument...

Comment: Declare your method like this instead: `private async Task<MergeInputDto> GetMergeInput(long param1, long param2, long param3)` - you don't need the second use of the type parameter.

Comment: So we found a solution where we changed the name of the parameter to `TMergeInputDto` and cast the result of the private method to `T`. But I think we're going to have to rethink the approach as this doesn't seem the way to go.